# comparing date using dd/mm/yy format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to write a program where i can compare current date with couple of dates that i have.

my data is

12 JUN 2016

21 MAR 1989

15 MAR 1958

15 SEP 1958

23 OCT 1930

15 SEP 1928

10 MAR 2010

23 JAN 1928

15 NOV 1925

26 AUG 2009

29 APR 1987

20 JUL 1962

10 MAY 1960

13 FEB 1955

10 MAR 1956

3 MAR 2010

14 NOV 1958

4 AUG 1985

24 AUG 1956

15 FEB 1955

19 MAY 1987

30 APR 1990

8 SEP 2014

18 JAN 2012

14 DEC 1960

1 AUG 1998

7 SEP 1963

9 MAR 2012

1 MAY 1990

14 MAY 1985

15 JUN 1945

5 APR 1995

26 FEB 1987

13 DEC 1983

15 AUG 2009

16 SEP 1980

16 JAN 2005

19 JUN 2011

Now how can i compare this to current date to know that date is not exceeding current date ( i.e 13/JUN/2016).

please help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `datetime` object using the string data. You can create the object by parsing the date string using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method.

```
from datetime import datetime    
mydate = datetime.strptime("19 JUN 2011", "%d %b %Y")
```

And then use the object to compare it with today's date.

```
print mydate < datetime.today()
True
```

Comment: You can edit your question. As the format is same across all the date string, only one date sample will suffice. No need to dump a lot of samples.